# Laravel 5.2 - Password Reset - Swift_TransportException

Tags: laravel-5, swiftmailer, password-recovery

I search the stackoverflow but couldn't find any solutions that can solve the problem.

```
Let me mention first that PHP built-in mail() function is working properly.
```

This problem occurred when I tried to send reset link from /password/reset page of Laravel 5.2 Auth.

First the error message:

> Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code
>   "550", with message "550 Missing internal data in the header. Message
>   discarded."

.env file settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

config/mail.php

```
'from' => ['address' => 'no-reply@domain.com', 'name' => 'Password Reset'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

Hope you guys get the point. Let me know if I need to provide anything else other than above information.

Comment: Are you wanting to use SMTP or php's build in `mail`?

Comment: @RossWilson 
I am not sure what does your question mean. But I just want to make it work. Either with smtp driver or mail driver.

About the php mail() I mentioned, that meant I tried mail() function directly to check if my mail server is okay. And its perfectly working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether the issue is still topical. But, according to [this topic on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/what-does-this-error-mean-swift-transportexception), try first to test the sending of the mail through the mailtrap.

For me it works for the default configuration of config/mail.php and such .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=secret000un
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret000pw
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Of course, you must write your own accesses from the working mailbox on the [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/).

You should get a standard Laravel letter to reset your password.

[image]